# Regenerate Wordpress Thumbnails from bash

Tags: wordpress, bash, thumbnails

Is there an easy way for me to regenerate image thumbnails after changing Settings > Media > Thumbnail size?

I know there are plugins for this but I have over 30k of images. Even the ajax one will take forever to complete.

I am on a VPS CentOS so I can run things like iconv, ffmpegthumbs etc so is there a way for me to do this task from bash?

**Update 1.**

Here is the script I wrote to do the job for me. I need to be in the folder which contains the images to run it.

```
#! /bin/bash
# Copyright Synvi Group (http://www.synvigroup.com)
# Custom script to generate wordpress thumbnails for smokingd
# Dependencies: Imagemagick, rename, coreutils
echo Checking if sgthumbs already exists...
rm -rf sgthumb &
wait
echo Checking if list file already exists...
rm -f  list &
wait
echo Generate list of files...
ls -1 --file-type | grep -v -e -[0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9] | grep -v -e -[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9] | grep -v -e -[0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | grep -v -e -[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | grep -v -e -[0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9] | grep -v -e -[0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9] | grep -v -e -[0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9] > list &
wait
echo Create sgthumb directory...
mkdir sgthumb &
wait
echo Copying files...
xargs -a list cp -t sgthumb/ &
wait
cd sgthumb
echo Generating thumbnails...
echo Processing jpg files..
mogrify -resize '610x200^' -gravity center -crop 610x200+0+0 +repage *.jpg &
wait
echo Processing png files..
mogrify -resize '610x200^' -gravity center -crop 610x200+0+0 +repage *.png &
wait
echo Appending the new size to filenames...
rename .jpg -610x200.jpg *.jpg &
wait
rename .png -610x200.png *.png &
wait
echo Fixing permissions...
chown smokingd:smokingd *
wait
chmod 777 *
wait
echo Moving thumbnails to main directory...
cp -p *.jpg ../
wait
cp -p *.png ../
wait
echo Cleaning up..
cd .. 
wait
rm -rf sgthumb
wait
rm list
wait
echo Done!
```

where USER is the user owning the files and PERMISSIONS are the correct ones for the files.

Now I need to update the database in order for older posts to use the new thumbnails.
The old posts use a thumbnail of 150x150 and the thumbnail used has -150x150 appended to its name.

**Update 2.**

The following query worked fine:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE (  
meta_value,  
'-150x150.jpg";s:5:"width";s:3:"150";s:6:"height";s:3:"150";}',  
'-610x200.jpg";s:5:"width";s:3:"610";s:6:"height";s:3:"200";}');
```

assuming original thumbnail size is 150x150 and the new size is 610x200.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at imagemagick

it comes with something called convert

convert $path/$file -resize x150 -define jpeg:extent=28kb $output/$file

so

```
sudo yum install imagemagick
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

**Step 1.** 
Tar up existing folder containing all images for backup

```
tar -cvzf images-backup.tar.gz images
```

**Step2**

```
mkdir /opt/image-test
cd /original/path/containing/images/
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p /opt/images/test/{} \;
```

The above is to create all folders that exist in current path in new image-test folder

```
#!/bin/bash

    path="/path/to/current-images"
    output="/opt/image-test/images"

       for files in `find $path -name \*.\* -print`
       do
        convert $path/$file -resize x150 -define jpeg:extent=28kb $output/$file
       done
```

i haven't test this but the reason you untarred the images to /opt/images then used original source to get image converted was because I was assuming the images were all in sub folders too which is why untarring would have created same directory structure and output result would be overwritten files in /opt/images-backup/images with the thumbnail results

you may need to tweak mess about but should work fine

Comment: thank you for this. I ended up doing something similar but in a slightly different manner. I edited my question to include the script I wrote if anyone else wants it. However I still don't know how to update all posts in the database to use the new thumbnail. A simple search and replace didn't work because of the way the post_meta tables are structured. Any way around this?

Comment: could take a look at this http://wordpress.org/support/topic/joining-postmeta-and-posts-table-to-get-image-urls, best place to ask maybe them or maybe a new wordpress question on here specific for the db structure question you have